# How do you access secret area of any USB device?

Tags: usb, driver, hardware, firmware, block-device

<strike>We know interfaces based on "vtable" principle. Once you have a pointer to an object, you can narrow-cast it to an interface and the new object is the same object but is very limited to the interface.  I always thought hardware **firmware** is somewhat similar. For example, for block devices (HDDs or SSDs), this interface is like **read**, **write**, **status** and similar. So **driver** is a user of such a device interface.</strike>

As it turns out, any storage device has **firmware** and a special area of its storage marked internal where firmware is saved. Manufacturers release programs that allow to "flash" their specific devices, e.g. by **writing new program to its internal space, hidden from the OS**.

My question is: on a software level, how do they perform this read-write operations to the "hidden" area of a drive? How dead "COM ports" are related?

If HDDs work across all OSes, why do firmware upgrade software is only released for Windows? In open source world of linux, what do i need to read to understand "debugging firmware" better?

Comment: "any storage device has firmware" - this is not true. Early platter storage devices from the 1950s and 1960s certainly did not have any firmware. Ditto, IBM PC-compatible storage devices from the 1980s had separate controller cards which implies the storage devices had no real "firmware" to speak-of.

Comment: @Dai Oh, maybe, I was thinking about USB devices there

Answer (score 2):

> We know interfaces based on "vtable" principle. Once you have a pointer to an object, you can narrow-cast it to an interface and the new object is the same object but is very limited to the interface. I always thought hardware firmware is somewhat similar. For example, for block devices (HDDs or SSDs), this interface is like read, write, status and similar. So driver is a user of such a device interface.

No, not really. Object-orientated programming is unrelated to personal computer hardware and your impression that `virtual` calls are relatable to device drivers is misguided. They're completely unrelated.

> As it turns out, any storage device has firmware and a special area of its storage marked internal where firmware is saved. Manufacturers release programs that allow to "flash" their specific devices, e.g. by writing new program to its internal space, hidden from the OS.

This is not true. Not all storage devices have firmware - and whatever firmware they have (if any) is not necessarily stored on rewritable flash-storage. [ROM chips exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-only_memory), for example, which are not rewritable.

> My question is: on a software level, how do they perform this read-write operations to the "hidden" area of a drive? How dead "COM ports" are related?

If you're referring to firmware updates of modern (post-2004) SATA and NVMe storage devices, then those devices' firmware can be updated using SATA and NVMe's built-in commands.

This is documented in places like  and [t13.org ATA/ATAPI Command Set - 4](https://www.t13.org/docsearch?title=ATA%2FATAPI+Command+Set+-+4&field_document_type_target_id_1=All&field_document_stage_target_id=All)

> If HDDs work across all OSes, why do firmware upgrade software is only released for Windows? In open source world of linux, what do i need to read to understand "debugging firmware" better?
>
> why do firmware upgrade software is only released for Window

Because Windows is the predominant operating-system used by users of those kinds of hardware. While the firmware can be updated using raw SATA/NVMe commands, you still need a host operating system to run the program that will issue those SATA/NVMe commands. Supposing it costs $100k to build a firmware update for an SSD for Windows and another $100k for Linux (for $200k for both Linux and Windows) - but 90% of all Linux users also run Windows - so why spend $200k for 100% coverage when you can spend $100k on 90% coverage, then spend the extra $100k buying a Ferrari or Tesla Model X P100D on yourself, and blame the users for not booting from a Windows USB stick to upgrade their firmware? (Side note: I chose the latter, and yes, I really do love my Tesla Model X)

You cannot have a program that just magically runs on any computer platform (Windows, BSD, Linux, macOS, QNX, etc) and updates periphial device firmware: it always needs to be a program that can be executed by a host OS (you can argue that UEFI/EFI is a platform-agnostic approach, but in reality UEFI/EFI is still its own platform)

> In open source world of linux, what do i need to read to understand "debugging firmware" better?

200mg of Adderall and a pirated copy of [IDA Pro](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/index.shtml).

...or 500mg of Dexedrine and [NSA Ghidra](https://www.nsa.gov/resources/everyone/ghidra/).

Comment: Thanks, clarifies a lot and gives great link. I'd try stick to 200mg variant

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the exact type of block device and how it is interfaced to the PC. A very common interface is SATA, when can be used directly with a SATA controller in a home PC - or it can be reached through a USB-SATA bridge.

If we take SATA as an example, there exists a special command in the SATA protocol known as "Download Microcode" (command ID 0x92) - which exists solely for the purpose of transferring new firmware to the drive controller.

The firmware is typically not stored on a "hidden area of the drive" itself, as your indicate - it is typically stored in flash memory or similar on the drive controller PCB or within the drive controller IC.

There are no "dead COM ports" involved in this.

The reason why harddrive vendors some times release firmware update tools only for Windows is probably the simple reason that most of their customers use Windows, and it is cheaper for them to simply support that one platform.